# How to prevent listbox items being dragged if mouse down is on certain controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like some advice on drag and drop operations of listbox items. Each of my items has a ComboBox, TextBox, CheckBox and Button, as shown below.

[image]

I use my drag/drop to reorder these and it is almost working correctly.

The main issue is that a drag operation on an item is occurring when a PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and PreviewMouseMove event happens on one of the controls noted above.

My question is given the code below what's good way I can prevent this drag occuring when one of the controls is clicked on?

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helpers:Filter}">
    <Border>
        <Border>
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox />
                <TextBox />
                <CheckBox />
                <Button />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox x:Name="FilterList"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}"
         helpers:DragDropHelper.IsDragSource="true" 
         helpers:DragDropHelper.IsDropTarget="true" />
```

C#:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSource", typeof(bool), typeof(DragDropHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsDragSourceChanged));


private void DragSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.sourceItemsControl = (ItemsControl)sender;
    Visual visual = e.OriginalSource as Visual;

    this.topWindow = Window.GetWindow(this.sourceItemsControl);
    this.initialMousePosition = e.GetPosition(this.topWindow);

    this.sourceItemContainer = sourceItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(visual) as FrameworkElement;

    if (this.sourceItemContainer != null)
    {
        this.draggedData = this.sourceItemContainer.DataContext;
    }
}

// Drag = mouse down + move by a certain amount
private void DragSource_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.draggedData != null)
    {
        // Only drag when user moved the mouse by a reasonable amount.
        if (Utilities.IsMovementBigEnough(this.initialMousePosition, e.GetPosition(this.topWindow)))
        {
            this.initialMouseOffset = this.initialMousePosition - this.sourceItemContainer.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), this.topWindow);

            DataObject data = new DataObject(this.format.Name, this.draggedData);

            // Adding events to the window to make sure dragged adorner comes up when mouse is not over a drop target.
            bool previousAllowDrop = this.topWindow.AllowDrop;
            this.topWindow.AllowDrop = true;
            this.topWindow.DragEnter += TopWindow_DragEnter;
            this.topWindow.DragOver += TopWindow_DragOver;
            this.topWindow.DragLeave += TopWindow_DragLeave;

            DragDropEffects effects = DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)sender, data, DragDropEffects.Move);

            RemoveDraggedAdorner();

            this.topWindow.AllowDrop = previousAllowDrop;
            this.topWindow.DragEnter -= TopWindow_DragEnter;
            this.topWindow.DragOver -= TopWindow_DragOver;
            this.topWindow.DragLeave -= TopWindow_DragLeave;

            this.draggedData = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you may perhaps cancel the event in the `DragSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event handler if the source of the event is not the desired element. `e.Handled=true` will mark the event consumed. in your logic seems like if you do not set `this.draggedData` there, the drag will not invoke in the  `DragSource_PreviewMouseMove` event handler. you may also try to find the respected control via `e.OriginalSource` by traversing the visual tree.

Comment: You created multiple usability problems.  The glitch when clicking the controls is bad enough, most severe one is that a user will never discover by himself that you support dragging.  Fix both problems by adding a glyph to the left that indicates that dragging works.  Now the user has a bulls-eye for the mouse too and you can eliminate confusion by only allow the D+D to start when the glyph is clicked and dragged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to initialise my Drag and Drop properties in a `PreviewMouseDown` event handler, but it's unwise to perform any other Drag and Drop operations in that handler, because the user might not be dragging... they might just have clicked.

Instead, it's better to handle the `PreviewMouseMove` event to initiate a Drag and Drop operation. Here is a simplified example:

```
private void DragSourcePreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = true;
}

private void DragSourcePreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseDown && IsConfirmedDrag(e.GetPosition(sender as ListBox)))
    {
        isMouseDown = false;
        ...
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, data, DragDropEffects);
    }
}
```

It is in the `PreviewMouseMove` event handler that you could check which UI element has been clicked on and determine whether you start the Drag and Drop operation or not. Try something like this:

```
private void DragSourcePreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox dragSourceControl = (ListBox)sender;
    HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(dragSourceControl, 
        Mouse.GetPosition(dragSourceControl));
    UIElement draggedUIElement = result.VisualHit.GetParentOfType<ListBoxItem>();
    bool isViable = AddYourViabilityConditionHere(draggedUIElement);
    if (isMouseDown && IsConfirmedDrag(e.GetPosition(sender as ListBox)) && isViable)
    {
        isMouseDown = false;
        ...
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, data, DragDropEffects);
    }
}
```